# Where is elmah.mvc log file located

Tags: elmah, elmah.mvc

After installing [elmah.mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC) from nuget:

where is the log file created by default?

Errors are logged just fine when I go to **/myapp/elmah** however I don't see where the actual log file resides.
thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Look at the bottom of the myapp/elmah page for "This log is provided by the..." to see what type of logging you're using. If it's In-Memory, there is no physical file. Otherwise, the location of the file is specified by logPath in web.config, such as...

```
 <elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~\App_Data\" />
 </elmah>
```

**EDIT**

I don't want to just replace the original code snippet because it might have worked for some people; for me it didn't and actually I had to change logPath a bit like that:

```
 <elmah>
  <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" />
 </elmah>
```

Comment: After I added that the xml files would still not show up until I added                write permissions and made App_Data folder NOT read only. thanks

Comment: @ShaneKm Can you update your question with all the changes you have done? like how did you made that folder not read only and gave write permissions etc.

Comment: I found that the App_Data folder is not the one in the MVC project but the one under IIS Express. For me it was 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\App_Data'

Answer (score 0):

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
      <section name="errorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.XmlFileErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="\\Mydocs\Logs" />
  </elmah>
```